# running mvn command on AWS ec2 linux throws No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-ec2

Running on AWS EC2 - Linux 
Java and mvn installed correctly
But while running `mvn clean test`, getting this error 
`No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?`
Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Have you checked what it says? That you have a JRE rather than a JDK installed? That means that your Java path doesn't contain programs like `javac`.

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: Yeah, I guess the name is confusing, but it looks like a JRE (Runtime Environment). If you can't run javac, you have no JDK.